# Need help to get two classes to assist each other

Tags: java, class

i'm currently just fooling around with different classes to test how they work together, but im getting an error message in NetBeans that i cant solve. Here's my code:

class first_class.java

```
public class first_class {

private second_class state;

int test_tal=2;

public void test (int n) {
    if (n>2) {
        System.out.println("HELLO");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("GOODBYE");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    state.john();
    TestingFunStuff.test(2);

}
}
```

class second_class

```
public class second_class {

first_class state; 

public int john () {
    if (state.test_tal==2) {
        return 4;
    }
    else {
        return 5;
    }
}
}
```

Apparently i can't run the method "john" in my main class, because "non static variable state cannot be referenced from a static context" and the method "test" because "non static method test(int) cannot be referenced from a static context".

What does this mean exactly?

Screenshot of the error shown in netbeans: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/26/funstufffirstclassnetbe.png/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means `state` must be declared as a static member if you're going to use it from a static method, or you need an instance of `first_class` from which you can access a non-static member. In the latter case, you'll need to provide a getter method (or make it public, but ew).

Also, you don't instantiate an instance of `second_class`, so after it compiles, you'll get a `NullPointerException`: static or not, there needs to be an instance to access an instance method.

---

I might recommend following Java naming conventions, use `camelCase` instead of `under_scores`, and start class names with upper-case letters.

Comment: thanks, i thought u could just create an object like i did and use all the methods from other classes like that, but i guess i got it a bit wrong, gotta read more into it

Comment: @John You defined/declared a class, but creating an object requires a "new" (at least as far as we're concerned right now). You'd need to do a "SecondClass state = new SecondClass();" somewhere along the line :)

Comment: Ok thanks. Would it be okay to extend First_class with Second class? Like "public class First_class extends Second_class"? Or would this create another scenario?

Comment: @John You *could*, if there's a reason, e.g., a FirstClass is-a SecondClass. That would change how you go about doing things, but not radically.

Comment: ok thanks for your help, will look into it more. i have a project atm, where we got a pre written program with 10 classes, so im trying to understand how they work together and when functions are called etc. by creating my own.

Comment: @John That's a good way to go about it, and the right attitude. If your using an IDE sometimes debugging/single-stepping can help, or just adding logging to provide some visibility and make sequential operations clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The trick here to get rid of the error message is to move the heavy work outside of main.  Let's assume that both lines are part of a setup routine.

```
state.john();
TestingFunStuff.test(2);
```

We could create a function called setup which contains the two lines.

```
public void setup() {
    state.john();
    TestingFunStuff.test(2);
}
```

Now the main routine can call setup instead, and the error is gone.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    setup();
}
```

However, the other members are correct in that your instantiation needs some cleanup as well. If you are new to objects and getting them to work together might I recommend the Head First Java book.  Good first read (note first not reference) and not all that expensive.

Comment: i am very new to objects and getting it all working together. thanks i will look into it

Answer (score 1):

Classes can have two types of members by initialization: static and dynamic (default). This controls the time the member is allocated.

Static is allocated at class declaration time, so is always available, cannot be inherited/overridden, etc. Dynamic is allocated at class instantiation time, so you have to `new` your class if you want to access such members...

It is like BSS vs heap (malloc'd) memory in C, if that helps..